# iOS: How do I notice when a view is behind a popover?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

In my application, I'm showing a popover, which causes all tinted UIImageViews behind the popover to desaturate. I want this behaviour also for UILabels and custom UIView subclasses on the screen. To achieve that, I need to observe when a popover opens, and when it closes, so I can update my colors manually.

My first approach was to observe the UIView's `tintColor` or `tintAdjustmentMode` properties. Like this:

```
override var tintAdjustmentMode: UIViewTintAdjustmentMode {
    didSet {
        // This does not get called
    }
}
```

However, these don't seem to get called, even though `self.tintAdjustmentMode` equals `true` when I check manually while a popover is shown.

Another approach would be to manually call a helper method from the ViewController that presents the popover (in this case a CollectionViewController). The problem with that is that this does not work when another ViewController (say the enclosing Navigation Controller) presents a popover. So that's not really what I want either.

What are other approaches that allow me to react to a popover being displayed over a view's current view controller?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, there is a UIView method `tintColorDidChange` to overwrite.

```
override func tintColorDidChange() {
    // This gets called
}
```

Apple Reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622620-tintcolordidchange